# PowerShell Impersonate in WorkFlow for Cim commands

Tags: powershell, workflow, workflow-activity

When running a `Windows PowerShell WorkFlow` it would be nice if it was possible to impersonate as another user and set up a `New-CimSession` for a connection to old servers (without PowerShell) using `DCOM` or new servers using `WSMAN`. There is online some [information](http://mikefrobbins.com/2012/09/20/targeting-down-level-clients-with-the-get-ciminstance-powershell-cmdlet/) available about this topic.

It's really difficult to start troubleshooting this with `Set-PSBreakPoint` as it can't access the flow going on in the part `InlineScript` which is very annoying.

However, every time I'm trying to run the following `Test-Stuff` WorkFlow it fails with a pop-up error `Windows PowerShell has stopped working`. In the console it says:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Error : The background process reported an error with the following message: .
At Test-Stuff:59 char:59
```

**The code:**

```
Workflow Test-Stuff {
   Param(
        [String[]]$Servers,
        [PSCredential]$Credentials
    )
     foreach -parallel ($S in $Servers) {
        InlineScript {
            $SessionParams = @{
                ErrorAction  = 'Stop'
                Credential   = $Using:Credentials
                ComputerName = $Using:S
            }
            Try {
                $Session = New-CimSession @SessionParams
            }
            Catch {
                $Opt = New-CimSessionOption -Protocol Dcom
                $Session = New-CimSession @SessionParams -SessionOption $Opt
            }

            $Params = @{
                ClassName    = 'Win32_Printer'
                Property     = '*'
                CimSession   = $Session
                ErrorAction  = 'Stop'
            }  
            if ($Printers = Get-CimInstance @Params) {
                $Printers
                Remove-CimSession $Session
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When running the same code as a normal function, it works just fine..

Comment: How about the `Switch` param to use `Invoke-Command -Credential`

Comment: That's some clever thinking. But it would be better to use a `CimSession` for this, as I only have to build it once. Because I'll do multiple `CIM queries` to one server.

Comment: Hmm, another workaround is to simply run `Powershell.exe` as the `Domain\User` that does have access to the resources.  Pay attention to where the script output will go, if any is created because permissions issues can crop up.

Comment: True, but the thing is that is has to start a new session to the remote machine on every WMI/CIM-call. Which isn't needed when you can set-up the session once with `New-CimSession`. In any case, thanks for your help already, much appreciated.

Comment: I'm unable to test but a quick web search turned up [this page](http://powershell.com/cs/forums/p/12448/22035.aspx) which mentions `What you need to do is to wrap your "CIM code" in inlinescript block.`

Comment: That is correct, it's also what I did as you can see in the code I posted.